# JQuery Datepicker get selectedmonth change event in codebehind

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, datepicker

i have a jquery-datepicker on my page :

```
<div id="COICalendar" class="datepicker ll-skin-vigo"></div>
```

The script looks as follows :

```
$("#COICalendar").datepicker();
```

This way I always see the complete month.
Now how can I capture the "onselectedmonthchange"-event (if that exists), in my codebehind file?

The reason I need to do that is because I want to several dates to get a specific color. And those dates come from a database.

Additionally I have several of the calendars on the same page, and I want them all to change to the same month when I change the month on one of those calendars.

Comment: jQuery's datepicker lets you set colors and stuff, but you'll have to output the data from the serverside, and then access it on the clientside and pass them to the `datepicker()` function.

Comment: @adeneo and how would I do that? Whenever the month is changed, I need to go to the database to get the dates for that month.

Comment: I don't really know .NET, but I'd assume ajax is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `beforeShowDay` event callback:

```
// css
.highlightedDate {
  /* highlight styles */  
}

// javascript
function paintDatepicker(specialDates) {
   $("#" + dateFieldId).datepicker({
       beforeShowDay : function(calDate) {

        /* This callback function will be invoked before painting each
         * date.
         * Perform required business validations here and then check
         * if the conditions are met.
         * You may access 'specialDates' here.
         */
        if (condition) {
            return [true, "highlightedDate", calDate];
        } 
    }
   });
}
```

Comment: And how would I get my "special dates" from codebehind to my page?

Comment: @BartSchelkens you could use ajax to call a handler

Comment: You can add this script in a function and pass on the special dates to the function. Edited my answer.

Comment: Sorry guys, must be monday. i'm not able to get my dates from the database to the ajax-call. Nor can I capture the onChangeMonthYear so I can set all calendars to the same date.